# 55-floors residential blocks next to the airport

Tags: airports, identify-this

Where is this picture taken?

[image]

Where in the world can I find 55-floor residential blocks in such a close proximity to an airport?

Comment: That's probably Hong Kong, the old [Kai Tak airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kai_Tak_Airport). I can't say for sure though. [Dragonair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonair) is a Hong Kong based regional airline, in operation since 1985 (Kai Tak closed in 1998).

Comment: It's also take with a telephoto lens, so the distances between the plane and buildings will appear compressed

Comment: https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/747/23600/B-KAC-Dragonair - this particular plane, B-KAC, was sold to Dragonair in 2002 and sent for scrapping 2008. So not Kai Tak.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, it could have been leased before 2002, who knows.

Comment: @Andrew your answer was correct.  You should undelete it.

Comment: @GregHewgill or Burhan Khalid has identified the wrong apartment towers in his answer.  The photo in question was taken in 2008.

Comment: @phoog not quite sure why I did that, must have got confused :) oh well, answered now...

Comment: I remember looking _up_ from a plane to the roof of a hotel while approaching San Diego.  But it wasn't 55 floors.

Comment: Note that simply using **a long focal length lens**, it looks (even more!) dramatic than it really was.  They're incredibly close compared to other major world airports, but not "that" close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct answer was posted by user [Andrew](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/29889/andrew), who has unfortunately deleted it.  Here it is:

> Here's [the original photo](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Dragonair-Cargo/Boeing-747-3H6M%28SF%29/1544714), with location given as:
>
> > Hong Kong - International (Chek Lap Kok) (HKG / VHHH)

Comment: I think it's [these buildings](https://www.google.com/maps/@22.2943382,113.9485668,3a,75y,185.23h,105.69t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1seFJ9APMw1hZRylF_i2h45g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1) just south of VHHH, but it's hard to be certain from the lower angle.

Comment: Yes, those buildings are in Tung Chung. The [Wikipedia page on Tung Chung](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tung_Chung) has a picture of the back of the same buildings. The building in the distance partially visible at the right hand edge of the same picture is at Chek Lap Kok.

Comment: Depending on landing runway, there's ca. 1.5 or even 3 kilometers between the airplane and the buildings on the picture.